# Can I have a generic spec file for multiple kernel version while creating rpm

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos7, rpm, rpm-spec

I am trying to build an rpm which includes a kernel module.
When i create it on centos i used %(uname -r) to copy the .ko in the module directory
`uname -r` expands to "3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64"

Now if i want to install the same ko on other system with same kernel version using rpm, it creates a separate folder for it i.e.

aka /lib/modules/3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 on the other system

Can i write a generic spec file that will copy the module to the specific folder. Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is [no longer an official way to do kernel modules](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Guidelines#No_External_Kernel_Modules). The `%(uname -r)` is populating at RPM build time; you cannot have a variable in your `%files` stanza.

As a workaround, I've put the module source in a reasonable location and then I build the driver in my `%post`. I also have a startup script that rebuilds on new kernel, because using `%triggerin` won't work. I uninstall the built kernel module on `%preun`.